# jQuery Validation require_from_group only validating first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with several fields and you gotta pick one.  So I used the 'require_from_group' functionality in jQuery validation.  The elements to be validated are some select elements and one text input element.  When I leverage the below validation, every element returns as false except for the first select regardless of selection/text input.  Am I doing something wrong, or missing something?

```
function validateRule() {

    validator = $('#frmRule').validate({
        debug: true,
        ignore: '.ignore, :disabled',
        rules: {
            reroute_to: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.action-group']
            },
            rename_to: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.action-group']
            },
            resettle_to: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.action-group']
            },
            map_ccy_to: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.action-group']
            },
            is_ignore: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.action-group']
            },
            is_field_72: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.action-group']
            },
            field_72_key: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(e) {
                        return !$(e).is(':hidden');
                    }
                }
            },
            field_72_value: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(e) {
                        return !$(e).is(':hidden');
                    }
                }
            },
            field_72_full: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(e) {
                        return !$(e).is(':hidden');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        groups: {
            actionGroup: 'reroute_to rename_to resettle_to map_ccy_to is_ignore field_72',

        },
        messages: {
            actionGroup: {
                require_from_group: 'At least one action is required to create a rule.'
            },
            field_72_key: {
                required: 'Both a key and value are required for a field 72 append action.'
            },
            field_72_value: {
                required: 'Both a key and value are required for a field 72 append action.'
            },
            field_72_full:
            {
                required: 'A full field 72 value is required.'
            }
        },
        errorLabelContainer: '.action-validation',
        submitHandler: function (form, e) {
            var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
            var data = {};
            $(form).serializeArray().map(function (x) {
                data[x.name] = x.value;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

HTML (snippet from larger form):

```
<div class="action">
                    <h3>I want to <strong>reroute</strong> to a <strong>
                        <a class="selectable" id="selected_reroute_to" href="#" data-modifier="">different
                            broker/BIC</a><span>.</span>
                        <select name="reroute_to" class="action-group" id="reroute_to" style="display: none;">
                            <option value="" selected>different broker/BIC</option>
                            % for b in brokers:
                                <option value="${b.id}">${b.name}</option>
                            % endfor
                        </select>
                    </strong>
                        <a href="#" class="reset"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="action">
                    <h3>I want to <strong>rename</strong> the fund(s) to <strong>
                        <a class="textable" class="action-group" id="selected_rename_to" data-modifier="" href="#">a new
                            code</a><span>.</span>
                        <input type="text" id="rename_to" name="rename_to" data-default="a new code"
                               value="a new code"
                               style="display: none;">

                    </strong>
                        <a href="#" class="reset"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="action">
                    <h3>I want to <strong>settle</strong> the trades
                        <strong>
                            <a class="selectable" class="action-group" id="selected_resettle_to" data-modifier=""
                               href="#">differently</a><span>.</span>
                            <select name="resettle_to" id="resettle_to" style="display: none;">
                                <option value="" selected>gross</option>
                                <option value="1">net</option>
                            </select>
                        </strong>
                        <a href="#" class="reset"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="action" style="display: none;">
                    <h3>I want to remap <strong>CCY</strong> to <strong>
                        <a class="textable" class="action-group" id="selected_map_ccy_to" data-modifier="" href="#">a
                            new currency
                            code</a><span>.</span>
                        <input type="text" id="map_ccy_to" name="map_ccy_to" data-default="a new currency code"
                               value="a new currency code" style="display: none;">
                    </strong>
                        <a href="#" class="reset"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="action">
                    <h3>I want to the trades to be
                        <strong>
                            <a class="selectable" class="action-group" id="selected_is_ignore" data-modifier=""
                               href="#">uploaded</a><span>.</span>
                            <select name="is_ignore" id="is_ignore" style="display: none;">
                                <option value="" selected>uploaded</option>
                                <option value="1">ignored</option>
                            </select>
                        </strong>
                        <a href="#" class="reset"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="action">
                    <h3>I want <strong>Field 72</strong> values to be
                        <strong>
                            <a class="selectable" class="action-group" id="selected_field_72" data-modifier=""
                               href="#">unaltered</a><span>.</span>
                            <select name="is_field_72" id="is_field_72" style="display: none;">
                                <option value="" selected>unaltered</option>
                                <option value="1">appended</option>
                            </select>
                        </strong>
                        <a href="#" class="reset"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="row" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field_72_key">Field 72 Key</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control field72 ignore" name="field_72_key" id="field_72_key">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field_72_value">Field 72 Value</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control field72 ignore" name="field_72_value"
                                       id="field_72_value">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field_72_full">Field 72 Field Replace</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control field72 ignore" name="field_72_full" id="field_72_full">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="action-validation alert alert-danger" style="display: none;" role="alert"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging.  The jQuery Validate plugin and the jQuery Validation Engine are not the same thing.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

and I'm an idiot.  I didn't have the 'action-group' class on the correct elements.  Ah jeez...

Comment: Thank-you for posting an honest answer.